# Javascript or Jquery - for each on this array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

See a screenshot of my returned data i did a console.log on which i need to do a for each on.

[image: array]

i have been trying things like this to no avail...?

```
for (var point in arrayLatLngPoints)
{
    addMarkers(point.timestamp, point.lat, point.lng, point.timestamp, strUserName, pathColour);
}
```

Comment: What's assigned to `point` inside the loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `for..in` to loop an array, use normal for loop instead.

```
for (var i = 0; i < arrayLatLngPoints.length; i++)
{
    var point = arrayLatLngPoints[i];
    addMarkers(point.timestamp, point.lat, point.lng, point.timestamp, strUserName, pathColour);
}
```

Comment: I think a brief explanation as to why they shouldn't use `for..in` to iterate over an array would make this answer a lot better.

Comment: Good info in https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in for why not to use `for..in`